# Session id is set even after logout

Tags: php, html, session

I'm trying to use session to keep the access to my website only to the authorized users.

Now, This is my main page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  require 'dbConfigBDO.php';
  require 'message.php';
  require 'SafeRedirect.php';

  if (isset($_POST['username']) AND isset($_POST['pass']))
  {
     $_SESSION['message'] = '';
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['pass'];

     $response= $conn->prepare('SELECT username,pass
                FROM AdminTable
                WHERE username = :nom
              ');
      $response->bindValue(':nom',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $response->execute();
      $member = $response->Fetch();
      $response->CloseCursor();

     if(!$member) exit('اسم المستخدم غير صحيح');
     if($password !== $member['pass']) exit('كلمة المرور غير صحيحه');
    
     $_SESSION['id'] = $member['username'];
     $_SESSION['message'] = htmlspecialchars($user). ' تم تسجيل دخولك بنجاح  ';
     safe_redirect('index.php');
     exit;
  }
?>

<!-- Log in:
First read name and password:-->
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <fieldset class="form-item">
        <legend>الدّخول</legend>
        <label for="email">الاسم</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
        <label for="pass">كلمة المرور</label><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="موافق">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem here is when I redirect the user to index.php which checks as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'message.php';
require 'SafeRedirect.php';
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$session_id = (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? $_SESSION['id'] : null;

if($session_id == null)
{
  $_SESSION['message'] = htmlspecialchars($user). ' Please sign in first... ';
   safe_redirect('login.php');
   exit;
}
?>
<a href="logout.php">
click here to log out</a>
```

Now when I press logout I shouldn't be able to access page index.php right?
the problem is I still can!
I tried to print the session ID and it does not change even after logout. I used

```
<?php
require 'SafeRedirect.php';
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["id"]);
session_regenerate_id(true);
session_destroy();
safe_redirect('login.php');
 ?>
```

my code use to work long time ago on another website but not now and I'm really confused what I did change since then.

Comment: Is [session.use_strict_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode) on?

Comment: is it a default option? because I did not set it anywhere in the code.

Comment: No default is off. See link. It should be set on.

Comment: I will set it on and check.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone nothing changed. I started my login page with it as I saw in the link.